# MySQL datatype float (8, 2) value getting rounded off to one decimal point when fetched in php with Laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-4.2

My database has a `float(8,2)` field and has a value with two decimal points (5.49). While fetching it to php, the value gets rounded to one decimal point (5.5) although I expect it to be to two decimal point (5.49) and not rounded off.

I found a solution by changing the datatype to `decimal`, but I can not do so for production environment (some reason). How can I restrict the round off?

I am using [laravel-4.2](/questions/tagged/laravel-4.2) [php-5.4](/questions/tagged/php-5.4) and [mysql-5.6](/questions/tagged/mysql-5.6) and [laravel-eloquent](/questions/tagged/laravel-eloquent).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the PHP code?

Comment: A quick test replicating your conditions, returns the correct value. Post your code, maybe there's something in there that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: `FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D)`. Here, `(M,D)` means than values can be stored with up to `M` digits in total, of which `D` digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as `FLOAT(7,4)` is displayed as `-999.9999`. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert `999.00009` into a `FLOAT(7,4)` column, the approximate result is `999.0001`.

Comment: ... and *then* the PHP layer might also add "its own spin on things."